# Did you see the cat?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, grammaticality

When there is a cat present in the room, how would you ask your one-year-old kid whether she see/saw the cat? 
-Did you see the cat?
-Do you see the cat?
-Have you seen the cat?

Comment: All three are fine, although "do you see the cat" asks if you see the cat *right now*.

Answer (score 1):

> "Do you see the cat?"

Asks about right now. Draws attention to the cat in the room.

> "Did you see the cat?"

Asks about earlier. If the child is no longer looking at the cat, but you want them recall something or go back and look at it.

> "Have you seen the cat?"

Asking if they have noticed the cat or where the cat is now. Usually used when the cat is not around and you are wondering where it is. So, probably not appropriate if the cat is in the room, unless this is the very first time the child has encountered this cat.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "Have you seen the cat?" is grammatically correct.

I think, it doesn't matter who you ask questions. It's good grammar which is important anywhere.